# Do we want a Meta MovieReel?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

[Our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1888/the-screening-room) has an [automated bot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-119/movie-reel) posting new questions from the main site but not one for meta questions. Seeing that meta activity isn't particularly high (though, chat activity isn't either), I often find myself manually posting links to recent and supposedly relevant meta questions in chat. We have a feed to notify the users currently in the room, but this isn't as persitent as an actual chat message (especially since the number of active users currently in the room often amounts to 0).

Thus I think **it would be a good idea to install an automated chatbot to post new meta questions, too**. Is this a good idea? If yes, how should it be named and who can do that, is it a task for the moderator(s)/room owners or SE employees only?

Comment: Its something that room owners can do I believe.  Let me see if I can work it out.

Comment: @iandotkelly yes you can do it easily but i am not sure about how to make bot user profile.

Comment: I believe I've set up a feed from meta to the Screening Room

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

I've been a bit more active on Meta in the last few days, but I definitely forget about it because it's not at the forefront of the site aside from the little block devoted to it on the right nav.

Therefore I'd totally be down for having a bot that posts new questions from Meta M&TV in chat.

Answer (score 0):

I liked that idea from start but i think Meta movies bot and movie reel sound and looks exactly same. Why can't he have fresh name and looks (DP). Like [Meta moose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-240/meta-moose) of Pets.SE .

Comment: I'd wait with that until the design is through (which *should* be in the very near future). Then the most appropriate would probably be the popcorn box (assuming that'll be our icon) for the non-meta bot and a b/w version of that for the meta one. I like the name for the non-meta bot (if only because that's what I'm used to for 3 years now), but ok, the meta bot name could use a bit more creativity. But all in all I'd deem this a post-graduation discussion, which there'll be enough anyway.