# Movies Meta Bot looks same as Movie reel

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, bot

Movies Meta Bot looks too much similar to Movie reel and they share the same dp.

Can't we have her/his new name and DP, like a popcorn theme picture and some funky name?

Already Raised this concern [before](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1488/do-we-want-a-meta-moviereel/1518#1518).

Comment: I believe this is something the site moderators can change

Comment: @Jin yup, i know that fact but i think this time is more suitable to raise this to out site mods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, now that the design is finished, those chat bots could be adapted. In particular the chat bot should have the site logo as user picture and the meta chat bot should have the black/white version of it.

About the name I'm not sure, but as uncreative as I am, I'd be content simply with *"Movies & TV"* and *"Movies & TV meta"* or something the like, or just keep this *"Movie Reel"* stuff and adapt the meta bot's name accordingly.